# maximum likelihood in double poisson distribution

Tags: r, mle

First I am using "rmutil" package to make simulation of double poisson distributed data. The difference of poisson and double poisson is that, double poisson allows overdispersion and underdispersion where mean and variance not necessary equal.

This link shows the function of double poisson distribution:
http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/rmutil/html/DoublePoisson.html

I have simulated a set of data with size of 500.

```
set.seed(10)
library("rmutil")

nn = 500 #size of data
gam = 0.7 #dispersion parameter
mu = 11

x <- rdoublepois(nn, mu, gam)
```

> head(x)
>
> [1] 11  9 10 13  6  8

```
 mean(x) #mean
 mean(x)/var(x) #dispersion
```

Below are the true value of parameters:

> mean(x) #mean
>
> [1] 10.986
>
> mean(x)/var(x) #dispersion
>
> [1] 0.695784

To obtain the parameter by MLE, I used nlminb function to maximize log likelihood function. The log likelihood function is formed by the density function of double distribution in "rmutil" package.

```
logl <- function(par) {
  mu.new <- par[1]
  gam.new <- par[2]

  -sum(ddoublepois(x, mu.new, gam.new, log=TRUE))
 }
nlminb(start = c(0.1,0.1), lower = 0, upper = Inf, logl)
```

It came out error:

> Error in ddoublepois(x, mu.new, gam.new) : s must be positive

So i make another attempt, I type in the equation of double poisson density function.

```
logl2 <- function(par) {
  mu.new <- vector() #mean
  gam.new <- vector() #dispersion
  ddpoi <- vector()


for (i in 1:nn){    
    ddpoi[i] <- 0.5*log(gam.new[i])-gam.new[i]*mu.new[i]
    +x[i]*(log(x[i])-1)-log(factorial(x[i]))
    +(gam.new[i])*x[i]*(1+log(mu.new[i]/x[i]))
  }
  -sum(ddpoi)
 }
nlminb(start = c(0.1,0.1), lower = 0, upper = Inf, logl2)
```

Output：

> nlminb(start = c(0.1,0.1), lower = 0, upper = Inf, logl2)
>
> $par
>
> [1] 0.1 0.1
>
> $objective
>
> [1] Inf
>
> $convergence
>
> [1] 0
>
> $iterations
>
> [1] 1
>
> $evaluations
>
> function gradient
>
> 2        4
>
> $message
>   [1] "X-convergence (3)"

Definitely, estimated parameters of 0.1 (same with initial value) shows that this code fails.

Anyone could show me how to do correct maximum likelihood estimation for double poisson distribution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your logl function shouldn't you be taking the log at some point

Comment: Hi Dason, i have tried this too, -sum(ddoublepois(x, mu.new, gam.new, log=TRUE)), but also return the same error message.

Comment: Note that it's not an "alternative". The alternative would be to take the product of the non logged version. But you can't just sum of you aren't taking the log.

Comment: Noted with thanks~ Dason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `nlminb` is trying to evaluate the function on the boundary (i.e. `s` exactly equal to 0).

One way to figure this out is to modify `logl` to include debugging statements:

```
logl <- function(par,debug=FALSE) {
    mu.new <- par[1]
    gam.new <- par[2]
    if (debug) cat(mu.new,gam.new," ")
    r <- -sum(ddoublepois(x, m=mu.new, s=gam.new,log=TRUE))
    if (debug) cat(r,"\n")
    return(r)
}
nlminb(start = c(0.1,0.1), lower = 0, upper = Inf, logl, debug=TRUE)
## 0.1 0.1 3403.035 
## 0.1 0.1 3403.035 
## 0.1 0.1 3403.035 
## 1.022365 0 Error in ddoublepois(x, m = mu.new, s = gam.new, log = TRUE) : 
## s must be positive
```

Now try it with the boundary displaced slightly from zero:

```
nlminb(start = c(0.1,0.1), lower = 1e-5, upper = Inf, logl)
```

Gives reasonable answers

```
## $par
## [1] 10.9921451  0.7183259
## ...
```

Comment: Dear @Ben Bolker, thank you for for your help. I still need to read more about the debug statement. I stuck at this problem for about 1 week and you have saved me! Hope that this answer could help more people.

Comment: Hi @Ben Bolker I know this is an old question but could you possibly comment on why using the density function dDPO in the gamlss package gives a different result for the dispersion parameter compared to ddoublepois in the rmutil package? I can setup a new question if that would be easier?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Sigma in the gam.lss package = 1/dispersion parameter in the rmutil package.